# How do I deploy an applet using JDeveloper?

Tags: applet, weblogic, jdeveloper

I have a simple applet that I have created in JDeveloper 11g R1, deploying to Weblogic server 10.3. This applet has a dependency of ojdbc6.jar. I am deploying as a war file.

When I deploy and browse to the html page the applet loads but I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource
```

I can see the ojdbc6.jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder when I expand the .war file.

The HTML of the applet page is as follows:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>
Title
</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<APPLET CODE="com.test.Applet" ARCHIVE="ojdbc6.jar" HEIGHT="800" WIDTH="625" ALIGN="bottom">This browser does not support Applets.</APPLET>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Is there a way to get JDeveloper to deploy so that my dependencies are actually accessible by the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an applet then the JDBC jar needs to be included in the applet JAR, not in the web project WAR.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that? I was under the impression that the archive attribute was where I could put jar files that I needed within the applet.

Comment: I think your way might work. But is you want it to be part of the JAR built for the applet edit your deployment profile for the project - there you can specify which libraries to include.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my issue is that even though I instructed JDeveloper to include libraries they don't show up in the generated jar file, very confusing.